MySQL Scheduled event next Execution time
I'm utilizing the MySQL Event Scheduler to run some SQL tasks. I have a task set to repeat and run every 14 days at 01:00, another task that runs every 31 days, and another task that runs every 50 days.
These scheduled tasks are running just fine, no issues.
Is there an easy way to find out when the event will next run, so I don’t have to manually pull out the calendar and count the days since last execution time?
I have searched google and come up empty.
I notice that SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events; will show the last execution time for each task, but nothing for the next planned execution time.

So why have you tagged SQL Server? Its a completely different RDBMS.

Retrieve needed info from The INFORMATION_SCHEMA EVENTS Table.

In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events you can DATE_ADD field INTERVAL_VALUE DAY to LAST_EXECUTED

I am intrigued by the notion that all 3 might occasionally run at the same time on the same day
